# navigation item does not change the title

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have simple view controller that is embedded in navigation controller, also I create by drag a'drop an bar button item to the right, connected it as action to the code and named it edit. So what I want it, if click on the button it should verify the title and change it if needed, here is the code:

```
class MyClass: ViewController {

  @IBAction func editButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

     if (self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title == "Edit") {
       self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title == "Done"
     } else {
       self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title = "Edit" 
     }
```

but its doesn't work. 
Thank ever for the advances

Answer (score 0):

If this wasn't a typo here, then the double == is the issue:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title == "Done"
```

Just change to

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.title = "Done"
```

Comment: You right, what a simple mistake. And I was thinking about so mush complex solutions:)

Answer (score 0):

if you use custom view with UIButton for rightBarButtonItem, then you can
use rightBarButtonItem.customView as UIButton. use button title compare

Comment: I dont wanna use and compare the custom view. My goal is to handle with navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem and to change those title after tapping on it